# Open the new of terminal via shell script

Tags: shell

Actually I am using putty. And I want to create a script by which we can open N no. of putty windows and adjust the size of that new terminal accordingly.

Please help me on this if it is possible.

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

With `Nautilus` you can execute your scripts, that open a gnome-terminal at the current location or the directory location you have selected.

This link exlpain it in details [Add Open Terminal Here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-gnome-open-terminal-shell-prompt-here/)

And this is the code:

```
base="`echo $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_CURRENT_URI | cut -d'/' -f3- | sed 's/%20/ /g'`"

if [ -z "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS" ]; then
     dir="$base"
else
     while [ ! -z "$1" -a ! -d "$base/$1" ]; do shift; done
     dir="$base/$1"
fi

gnome-terminal --working-directory="$dir"
```

Comment: Thanks MikroDel...But it is not working.. Getting some error
(gnome-terminal:24954): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:

Comment: @sharad - you should also read and **understand** this article: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-gnome-open-terminal-shell-prompt-here